# How do i get a post id in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i am new to Laravel so am trying to delete and edit some posts which is linked to a page where the update from is located but each time i update or delete, i get a 404 error or the page is not found(i think the problem is the url).

here is my code for the update

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)   {
$car = Car::where('id', $id)
     ->update([
        'name'=> $request->input('name'),
        'founded'=> $request->input('founded'),
        'description' => $request->input('description')
]);

return redirect('/cars'); }
```

this one is for delete/destroy

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $car = Car::find($id);
    $car->delete();
    return redirect('/cars');
}
```

i also have an edit.blade.php

```
@section('content')
<div class="m-auto w-4/8 py-24">
    <div class="text-center">
        <h1 class="text-5xl uppercase bold">
            Update Car
        </h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="flex justify-center pt-20">
    <form action="../cars/{{ $car->id }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('PUT')
        <div class="block">
            <input type="text" class="shadow-5xl mb-10 p-2 w-80 italic placeholder-gray-400" name="name" 
            value="{{ $car->name }}"><br>

            <input type="number" class="shadow-5xl mb-10 p-2 w-80 italic placeholder-gray-400" name="founded" 
            value="{{ $car->founded }}"><br>

            <input type="text" class="shadow-5xl mb-10 p-2 w-80 italic placeholder-gray-400" name="description" 
            value="{{ $car->description }}"><br>

            <button type="submit" class="bg-teal-500 block shadow-5xl mb-10 p-2 w-80 uppercase font-bold text-white">
              Update
            </button>
            
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

@endsection

the last part contains the buttons for delete and edit

```
 @foreach ($cars as $car )
            <div class="m-auto">
                
                <span class="uppercase text-teal-500 font-bold text-xs italic">
                    Founded : {{ $car->founded  }}
                </span>
                <h2 class="text-gray-700 text-5xl">
                  {{ $car->name }}
                </h2>
                <p class="text-lg text-gray-700 py-6">
                    Description : {{ $car->description }} 
                 </p>
                 <div class="float-right">
                    <a class=" pb-2 italic text-teal-500" href="cars/{{ $car->id }}/edit">
                      Edit &rarr;
                    </a>

                    <form action="../cars/{{ $car->id }}" method="POST">
                     @csrf
                     @method("delete")
                    <button type="submit" class="pb-2  italic text-red-500">
                        Delete &rarr;
                    </button>
                    </form>
                  </div><br><br>

            <hr class="mt-4 mb-8">
            </div>
       @endforeach
```

here is my route

```
Route::resource('/cars', CarsController::class);
```

Comment: What URL do you get a 404 on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first check route with this command `php artisan route:list`
then you see list like this

```
DELETE          cars/{car}
PUT|PATCH       cars/{car}
```

the `car` name is important to automatically Laravel find entity base on Type hint `Car $car`, so in controller use this convention :

```
public function destroy(Car $car)
{
    $car->delete();
    return redirect('/cars');
}
public function update(Request $request, Car $car) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not generate url like this: `action="../cars/{{ $car->id }}"`

Instead use `action="{{ route('cars.update', $car->id) }}"`

You can see the available routes by running this command
`php artisan route:list`

Comment: You have come to my rescue Mahmudul Hasan it has really worked. I appreciate

Answer (score 0):

So, Basically when you use resource you get predefined route list by Laravel with different methods.

> Example your route is

```
Route::resource('/cars', CarsController::class);
```

> Then laravel generate routes like this.
> To check route list run `php artisan route:list`

```
Route::GET('/cars', [CarsController::class, 'index'])->name('cars.index');
Route::GET('/cars/create', [CarsController::class, 'create'])->name('cars.create');
Route::POST('/cars', [CarsController::class, 'store'])->name('cars.store');
Route::GET('/cars/{id}', [CarsController::class, 'show'])->name('cars.show');
Route::GET('/cars/{id}/edit', [CarsController::class, 'edit'])->name('cars.edit');
Route::PUT('/cars/{id}', [CarsController::class, 'update'])->name('cars.update');
Route::DELETE('/cars/{id}', [CarsController::class, 'destroy'])->name('cars.destroy');
```

Then you can use in form with defined methods.

> ```
> Example to use
> ```

```
 {{ route('cars.destroy', ['id' => $car->id]) }}
```

Source Laravel documentation: [click to check more resource method](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#restful-partial-resource-routes) on offical Laravel website.

Comment: thank you Sahil, let me try that